# Personalized bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographystyle

In my University, for some reason, they are making me do this type of Bibliography for my thesis:

[image: Bibliography requested]

Any idea how to do it?

At the moment I'm having this code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, doi=false, eprint=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\trivlist}
  {\endtrivlist}
  {\item
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
  \hspace*{10mm}}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
Some text.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code:]

Unfortunately, it's not quite what I need. Can Any one help?

This is the .bib file

```
@Article{Jose,
  author    = {José Joaquín Brunner},
  title     = {Globalización, Educación y Revolución tecnológica},
  journal   = {Perspectivas},
  year      = {2001},
  volume    = {31},
  pages     = {139--154}
}

@Article{Carmen,
  author    = {Carmen Rosa Coloma Manrique},
  title     = {El constructivismo y sus implicaciones en educación},
  journal   = {Educación Colombia},
  year      = {1999},
  volume    = {8},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {217--229}
}

@Misc{TIC,
  author    = {Rosa María Tafur Puente},
  title     = {Características de las TIC:Inmaterialidad},
  year      = {2015},
  url       = {http://manuelantoniomm.blogspot.com/2015/04/caracteristicas-de-las-ticinmaterialidad.html},
  day       = {04},
  month     = {03},
  year      = {2018},
  journal   = {Educación Colombia}
}

 @Misc{Plataforma,
  author    = {Manuel Antonio Marquez},
  title     = {Características de las TIC: Inmaterialidad},
  year      = {2018},
  url       = {http://www.ticeducacionec.com/2014/05/30-plataformas-virtuales-educativas.html},
  day       = {04},
  month     = {03},
  year      = {2018},
  journal   = {Educación Colombia},
  journal   = {TIC Educación}
}

 @Article{RUSC,
  author    = {Stefany Hernández Requena},
  title     = {El modelo constructivista con las nuevas tecnologías: aplicado en el proceso de aprendizaje},
  journal   = {Revista de Universidad y Sociedad del Conocimiento},
  year      = {2008},
  volume    = {5},
  number    = {11},
  pages     = {26--35}
}

 @Book{Instru1,
  author     = {William David Cooper},
  title      = {Instrumentación Electrónica Moderna y Técnicas de Medicón},
  year       = {1991},
  publisher  = {Prentice-Hall Hispanoamérica S.A},
  address    = {M{\'e}xico}
  }

 @Book{Metro1,
  author     = {Jaime Restrepo Diaz},
  title      = {Metrología : aseguramiento metrológico industrial},
  year       = {2007},
  publisher  = {Instituto Tecnológico Metropolitano},
  address    = {Medell{\'i}n, Colombia}
  }

 @Book{Paco,
  author     = {Francisco Javier González Lopez},
  title      = {Metrología: Ejemplos Eléctricos y otras magnitudes},
  year       = {1995},
  publisher  = {Universidad de San Carlos de Guatemala},
  address    = {Ciudad de Guatemala}
  }

 @Book{Metro2,
  author     = {T W Hansch and Sigfrido Leschiutta and A J Wallard},
  title      = {Metrologia e costanti fondamentali},
  year       = {2007},
  publisher  = {Società Italiana di Fisica},
  address    = {Bologna, Italia}
  }

 @Book{DataError,
  author     = {Philip Bevington and D Keith Robinson},
  title      = {Data Reduction and Error Analysis For the Physical Sciences},
  year       = {2003},
  publisher  = {McGraw-Hill Education},
  address    = {University of California}
  }
 @Book{PhyMet,
  author     = {Alexius J Hebra},
  title      = {The Physics of Metrology},
  year       = {2010},
  publisher  = {SpringerWien New York},
  address    = {Charleston SC, USA}
  }

  @PHDThesis{BioIns,
  author     =  {Enrique Mario Spinelli},
  title      =  {Amplificadores de Instrumentación en Aplicaciones Biomédicas},
  school     =  {Universidad Nacional de la Plata},
  year       =  {2001}
} 
  @techreport{BioIns2,
  author     =  {Lorena Alvarez Osorio},
  title      =  {Acondicionamiento de Señales Bioeléctricas},
  institution =  {Universidad Tecnológica de Pereira},
  year       =  {2007},
  address   = {Medellín, Colombia}
} 

 @techreport{BioIns3,
  author =       {J F Guerrero},
  title =        {Ingeniería Biomédica},
  institution =  {Universitat D' Valencia},
  year =         {2011},
  address   = {Valencia, España}
} 


 @Article{labBio,
  author  = {R. Pallás-Areny and J. Colominas},
  title   = {Simple, fast method for patient body capacitance and power line electric measurement},
  journal = {Medicine and Biology Engineer and Computational},
  year    = {1991},
  volume  = {1}
}

@Book{Penr,
  author     = {R. Penrose},
  title      = {La mente nueva del emperador},
  year       = {1996},
  publisher  = {Fondo de Cultura Econ{\'o}mica},
  address   = {M{\'e}xico}
}

@manual{Auto,
title = {FA Equipment for Begginners},
author = {Susumu Watanabe},
organization = {Mistubishi Electric Corporation},
address = {Tokyo, Japón},
year       = {2014}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. The manual says the `addendum` field is for "Miscellaneous bibliographic data to be printed at the end of the entry." So if you add `addendum = {80 p},` to the bib file, it will print like in your example. Finding the number of pages for each work will take time.

Comment: Alternatively, `pagetotal = {123},` will print with the localised version for plural of "pages', eg, `123 pp.` in English.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start.

The most interesting bit was probably adding support for `\bibhang` to a numeric bibliography environment for the added indent in the second line of an entry.

The rest was fairly basic stuff explained in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

Note that multi-word family names need to be given in the from

```
author    = {González López, Eduardo},
```

and *not* as

```
author    = {Eduardo González López},
```

for Biber and BibTeX to properly recognise what is given and what family name.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}

%\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}
%\setlength{\biblabelsep}{.5cm}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{gonzlop,
  author    = {González López, Eduardo},
  title     = {Geometría analítica},
  edition   = {3},
  year      = {2010},
  publisher = {Piedra Santa},
  location  = {Guatemala},
  pagetotal = {80},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,gonzlop}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: González López, Eduardo. Geometría analítica. 3. a ed. Guatemala: Piedra Santa, 2010. 80 págs.]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!